# Re: GCD with Firebase Swift to update data

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to populate my table and I am fetching a couple of different data from firebase. One of my code is below:

```
 //Firebase
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let dataLoad = DispatchGroup()
    let backgroundQ = DispatchQueue(label:"queue", attributes: .concurrent)


    ref.child("Vendor Reviews/\(id)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for child in snapshot.children {

            dataLoad.enter()

            backgroundQ.async(group: dataLoad, execute: {

            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = dict?["username"] as! String
            let rating = dict?["rating"] as! Double
            let review = dict?["review"] as! String
            let image = dict?["image"] as! String
            let timestamp = dict?["date"] as! TimeInterval

            let rawDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)

            let date = String(describing: rawDate)

            let comment = VendorCommentCellData(img: image, name: username, date: date, comment: review, rating: rating)

            comments += [comment]

            print("Added 1")

                dataLoad.leave()

            })

        }

    })


    dataLoad.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main){
        print("All added")
    }
```

For some reason, in the console log, print("All added") is always appearing before print("Add 1") and as a result, I am not able to know when my data is retrieved and thus unable to populate my table at all.

I got this to work before in Swift 2 and I wrote it in the same way but it does not work.

Do let me know where did my code go wrong. I am new to swift and I am not good with GCD at all. Hope you all can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
let dataLoad = DispatchGroup()
let backgroundQ = DispatchQueue(label:"queue")

backgroundQ.async(group: dataLoad) {
//etc..
}

dataLoad.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main){
    print("All added")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added a print in the backgroundQ part but it still got printed after "All added" is printed

Comment: take out: dataLoad.enter() and dataLoad.leave()